# when I use Connectivity.java

Tags: java, imagej

I used this code：

https://github.com/bonej-org/BoneJ2/blob/master/Legacy/bonej/src/main/java/org/bonej/plugins/Connectivity.java

I built `Connectivity.jar`.
I use it like `this：IJ.runPlugIn("Connectivity.Connectivity", "");`

But it can't calculate the value of Connectivity.

The following is an exception：

```
Exception in thread "Run$_main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
        at cleo_new.CLEO2_interface.putResultToInterface(CLEO2_interface.java:626)
        at
cleo_new.CLEO2_interface.computeMicroarchitecture(CLEO2_interface.java:511)
        at
cleo_new.CLEO2_interface.Launch_computationActionPerformed(CLEO2_interface.java:209)
        at cleo_new.CLEO2_interface.<init>(CLEO2_interface.java:35)
        at cleo_new.CLEO_NEW.main(CLEO_NEW.java:30)
```

Comment: If you haven't already, I strongly suggest you post this question on https://forum.image.sc/ with the `bonej` tag.